# Lookup value in table and interlope the data

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance for your time. I am trying to create a function where you input if a bond is CORP_AAA, CORP_AA, and so on. Secondly the function would identify the duration of the bond 1-50. The output would be the associated figures in the table provided in the link. Any duration figures that is a decimal (2.33 or 4.44) would interlope the associated figures for the duration bands the number falls within.

Struggling to find an efficient way to code this up without just hard coding 800 lines. Any suggestions on how to condense the code?

[image]

```
Option Compare Text

Function DefaultAdj(RiskCategory As String, Duration As Double)

Dim SDuration2 As Double
SDuration2 = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, Duration)

' Use Spread Duration
If RiskCategory = "Corp_AAA" Then
    If SDuration2 < 1 Then
        Default = 0
    ElseIf SDuration2 >= 1 And SDuration2 < 2 Then
       Default = 0.00012
    ElseIf SDuration2 >= 2 And SDuration2 < 3 Then
        Default = 0.00012
    ElseIf SDuration2 >= 3 And SDuration2 < 4 Then
        Default = 0.00035
    ElseIf SDuration2 >= 4 And SDuration2 < 5 Then
        Default = 0.00061
```

Comment: Realize the picture doesn't show up. It is a table with Duration 1-50 as the row header. The column header is Corp_AAA, Corp_AA, on down. The associated values are my default expectations in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about round up duration and then use matrix search?

Considering duration in columns (1-50) is increasing by 1:

```
Function DefaultAdj(RiskCategory As String, Duration As Double)
    Dim upper_value As Integer, lower_value As Integer
    Dim Duration_rounded_up As Integer, Duration_rounded_down As Integer
    Dim difference_between_values As Double
    
    Duration_rounded_up = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Duration, 0)
    Duration_rounded_down = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Duration, 0)
    
    upper_value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B2:Z5"), WorksheetFunction.Match(RiskCategory, Range("A2:A5"), 1), WorksheetFunction.Match(Duration_rounded_up, Range("A1:Z1"), 1))
    lower_value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B2:Z5"), WorksheetFunction.Match(RiskCategory, Range("A2:A5"), 1), WorksheetFunction.Match(Duration_rounded_down, Range("A1:Z1"), 1))
    
    difference_between_values = upper_value - lower_value 
    
    result = (Duration - Duration_rounded_down) * difference_between_values

    DefaultAdj = lower_value + result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The rounding up won't work because I need actual figures. for example if duration is 3.4 I need to linearly interlope what 3.4 would be. Although the matrix search looks to be helpful in condensing the code down a bit.

Comment: I think you dont specify that requirement in the question and not obvious from example. However you can do two lookups: one for rounded up and second for rounded down, then calculating value between should be easy.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you find it useful, please consider accepting answer.